# Wordpress: saving and using data from form

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a quiz contest on a WordPress site. The visitor will fill his/her name, phone, email and facebook id and answer two questions. I need to view and later use the data submitted in the form. Also A thanks message will automatically go to the visitor's email after submitting the form.
Can anyone please guide me how can I accomplish this? Which plugin can be used to fulfill the requirement?
Any guidance will be much appreciated.
Thanks
Placid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using Contact Form 7 (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) to build the form, and then Contact Form DB (https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/) to view data in the backend.

Comment: Thanks @goodpixels. Can you please tell me what formats the CFDB plugin exports data to?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the available options: http://postimg.org/image/p5zti9mo9/

Answer (score 1):

I use Contact Form 7 for my wordpress forms. It is free and vary flexible. Make sure you read some tutorials before using if you are not comfortable with some basic HTML.

There is a section called "Mail 2" that would allow you to send the thank you email to the user, and still have the form info that they entered be sent to you.

Link to the plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Good luck!